# unable to access laravel blade template code from external jquery file

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am new  on laravel  and using blade template in somewhere on my view I need to move some images of a team division and I am using JQuery for that this is my code

```
$('#next').click( function (){
    //$.fn.myFunc();
    //alert("{{$team['count_team']}}");

    var j=0;
    for (var i = current;i < {{$team['count_team']}}&& j<1; i=i+3) {
        $('#team1').attr("src", team_src[i+2]);
        $('#team2').attr("src", team_src[i+1]);
        $('#team3').attr("src", team_src[i]);
        $('#name1').text(team_name[i+2]);
        $('#name2').text(team_name[i+1]);
        $('#name3').text(team_name[i]);
        j=1;
        current=current+3;
    }
});
```

everything is working fine when I place the code in my view but when I call the following JQuery code from an external file its shows an error for loop condition "invalid property id" 
How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have Laravel Blade code in your JavaScript. That is fine as long as it is included directly in a PHP (view) file, but it won't work in a standalone JavaScript file.

Externally-linked JavaScript files are not parsed by Laravel Blade because they are loaded by the client directly, and after the server has already interpreted the PHP code.

One way to get around this problem is to write anything that needs to be output from PHP as a global javascript variable in your view. Then, your external file will be able to access it. Something like this:

in myview.php

```
<script>
count_team = {{$team['count_team']}};
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/myscript.js') }}"></script>
```

in js/myscript.js

```
$('#next').click( function (){
    var j =0 ;
    for (var i = current;i < count_team && j<1; i=i+3) {
        $('#team1').attr("src", team_src[i+2]);
        $('#team2').attr("src", team_src[i+1]);
        $('#team3').attr("src", team_src[i]);
        $('#name1').text(team_name[i+2]);
        $('#name2').text(team_name[i+1]);
        $('#name3').text(team_name[i]);
        j=1;
        current=current+3;
    }
});
```